# Eliminating DateDiff in SQL Server where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking at a query with, as part of the where clause, `DateDiff(month, table1.dateReported,  table2.dateTransDate) <= 6`, where dateReported and dateTransdate are in different tables. I recently read that using SQL functions in a where clause can cause performance issues. How can I alter this to not use the datediff?

It's basically a view with something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.transactionID = Table2.transactionID 
WHERE DateDiff(month, Table1.dateReported,  Table2 .dateTransDate) <= 6
```

Comment: that will not be your primary concern, why would not you use build in function if they've already pointed you a shortcut xD

Comment: Are datereported and datetransdate in the same table  or separate tables? If the same it won't be sargable whatever (at least without creating a custom computed column) If separate you can make it sargable for one column but not the other. Which will be best depends.

Comment: Please include the query you already have in your question. Make it clear from which table(s) the columns in your DateDiff expression come from.

Comment: @TT. I added it. It's nothing overly complicated, and really I'm not seeing performance issues right now, but if there is room for improvement I'd like to learn it.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause turns that `LEFT JOIN` back into an `INNER JOIN` by the way.

Comment: @MartinSmith I didn't think of that, I was just trying to make my example as simple as possible, but looking at my original query, I think it does end up the same. Is there a reason not to leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE  Table1.dateReported >=  
   /*First day of the month six months previous to Table2.dateTransDate*/
   DATEADD(month, -6 + DATEDIFF(month, 0, Table2.dateTransDate), 0)
```

to potentially allow an index on `Table1.transactionID, Table1.dateReported` to be used.

Or

```
Table2.dateTransDate <=  
  /*Last day of the month six months after Table1.dateReported*/
  DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month, 7 + DATEDIFF(month, 0, Table1.dateReported), 0))
```

to potentially allow an index on `Table2.transactionID, Table2.dateTransDate` to be used.

[A test rig is here to validate it for a cross joined year of dates to ensure all three return the same results](http://rextester.com/RDKC42520).

Comment: This does seem to have shaved ~1 second off of the query, so pretty cool thing to have learned.